# How to use Google File Stream's root instead of "My Drive" subfolder?

Tags: google-drive

Good old Google Drive had my files at the root which I find normal. Google File Stream has them in a "My Drive" sub-folder which I find pretty annoying (there's also a "Team Drives" that I have no use of).

Is there a way to somehow move my files to the root and remove these 2 sub-folders?

My Options menu:
[image]

Comment: Google File Stream does not [appear](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/7638428?hl=en) to allow you to choose which folder you will sync.  However, I don't have access to the client, to check what the configurations options are.  Can you provide that information to us?  I do know you can configure which folder, your files will be synchronized from, if you were to use `Backup and Sync`

Comment: I edited to show option menu, but there's basically no options...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that the answer is negative.
Google File Stream is an evolution of Google Drive, which by its nature
introduces new complexities.

You are asking for a modification of the way that the Google File Stream server
displays its result.
However, the Google Support page of
[Configure Drive File Stream](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7644837?hl=en&vid=0-689142231790-1527441597964)
only lists parameters for the client version,
but no configuration parameters for the server side.

My Drive Folders and Team Drive Folders are two different ways for you
to share your data. Both are available, even if you use only one.

Team Drive is oriented more toward team work.
It allows more advanced permission and ownership
by having two permission levels: Full access and Edit access.
The later only allows a member to make changes to the files within the Team Drive, or add new files.
Full access is required to manage folder permissions and to remove or delete files.

My Drive folders represent the classic Google Drive method that allows
public link sharing.
They allow unrestricted public access and allow different sharing permissions
to be set at the subfolder level.
But they lack the granular editing permissions available in Team Drive.

For more information about the two methods, see the article
[Folder Management in G Suite: My Drive vs Team Drive](https://www.wursta.com/technical/folder-management-in-g-suite-my-drive-vs-team-drive/).

Other places in which you may find help or be able to suggest a new feature are:

- [Google Product Forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!home)
- [Google Drive Help](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/7329379)
- [G Suite Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/apps)
  (if you're using a G-Suite account)